# plyr : problem naming columns output with ddply

Tags: r

I don't understand how naming of columns worked on `ddply`.

I tried the following example which works well

```
data <- data.frame(nom=c("a","b","c","a","b","a"))

#good result but column name V1 by default
ddply(data,.(nom),nrow)

  nom V1
1   a  3
2   b  2
3   c  1

# bad result
ddply(data,.(nom), NB=nrow)

  nom
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   b
5   b
6   c
```

In bad result example I hopped to obtain the same result as in good result example but with column name V1 replaces by NB.

Comment: you could use `dplyr`, `data %>% group_by(nom) %>% summarise(NB = n())`

Answer (score 0):

I think group is not the best option here. I would use count:

```
data %>% count(nom, name = "NB")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  nom      NB
  <chr> <int>
1 a         3
2 b         2
3 c         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. Count makes the job in this example it's true. 
I choose nrow fonction for an easy reproductible example but the problem is the same with most function used with ddply.

I could also do 
`result<-ddply(data,.(nom),nrow)
names(results)<-c("NOM", "NB")`

but I keep not understanding why I can't rename directly column of result with ddply.

If anybody as the answer, thank you very much.